# create list with dynamic object or entity C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

### i want this

```
public class MonthEntity
        {
            public int monthid { get; set; }
            public string Date_01_01_2016 { get; set; }
            public string Date_02_01_2016 { get; set; }
            public string Date_03_01_2016 { get; set; }
            public string Date_04_01_2016 { get; set; }
            public string Date_05_01_2016 { get; set; }
        }
```

But using Code like create

```
List<MonthEntity> list=new List<MonthEntity>();
```

add object like DataTable create columns dynamically

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
string[] cols={"01","02",.....All any month dates};
foreach(string s in cols)
{
   dt.Columns.Add(s);
}
```

like data table i want to create list with dynamic columns.....

Comment: I'm assure you there no need to create Date_01_01_2016...Date_05_01_2016. It's look like you need 1 collection that with hold all your columns  objects

Comment: Please take some time to write a proper question that clearly explains what the problem is and what you are asking. If *you* can't write the question, how do you expect other people to understand it and gie a good answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your entity like this:

```
public class MonthEntity
{
    public int monthid { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> TheDate { get; set; }
}
```

and then add each date as an entry into the dictionary field